# How to setup a proxy to unblock a url using PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, proxy

A client of mine has `youtube.com` blocked via firewall and they are trying to watch embedded videos that are on my system. What is a good way to proxy those URLs to bypass their block?

Here is a plugin/website I am interested in: [PHP plugin](https://github.com/Athlon1600/php-proxy) and [Website that unblocks Youtube videos](https://unblockvideos.com)

I don't want them to type in a URL, they will be navigating to my system and watching EMBEDDED YouTube videos. Does anyone have any insight on what to do?

I am willing to work with someone on making this work.

EDIT: here is how I am displaying the video:

```css
$('.video-zoom').magnificPopup({
                    disableOn: 700,
                    type: 'iframe',
                    mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
                    removalDelay: 160,
                    preloader: false,

                    fixedContentPos: false
                });
```

```html
<a href="{{URL::to('/') . '/video/embed/' . $item['id']}}" class="video-zoom" title="View Video" data-toggle="tooltip">
<i class="icon fa fa-search"></i>
 </a>
```

Comment: Why not just VPN or SSH tunnel? You could also self-host the videos if they're just MP4, the `<video>` tag is totally a thing.

Comment: Why not just simply accept the fact that your client has had their access to YouTube blocked for a *reason*?

Comment: That is too complicated for the clients who might have it blocked. I would like them to just be able to navigate to the website, and if the site is blocked, a proxy is set so they can see the embedded videos.

Comment: That is out of our hands. Our system lets them upload private videos to youtube via cellular, but when it comes to getting on the Web app to review the videos, they are blocked.

Comment: @tadman would replacing `iframe` with `video` work? Or would I need to use a plugin like https://github.com/sampotts/plyr in my laravel project?

Comment: Added code examples for explanation.

Comment: There's a hundred ways to embed video, YouTube is just one. If you're dealing with firewall restrictions that are difficult to subvert then look at what options you have. Self-hosting is one solution, like using [Videojs](https://videojs.com) or [JWPlayer](https://www.jwplayer.com) against raw media files.

Comment: Unfortunately, moving away from YouTube would a bigger hassle since the Mobile app we created uploads directly to YouTube as a private video and it is tied into the system pretty widely. So moving from YouTube hosted video to self-hosted video would be too large. Is the proxy idea I had in the OP still possible with embedded videos?

Comment: Not much related to problem, but please use this way `{{URL::to('/video/embed/' . $item['id']) }}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scripts like that won't be able to proxy streaming media from other sites. You'll only be able to proxy the standard HTTP requests and assets. Your easiest bet is to run a VPN to get around any DNS or network blocks.

I'm not a huge fan of Node.js, however it's much better at streaming and asynchronous code, so take a look at this repo: https://github.com/licson0729/node-YouTubeStreamer